# formatDate angular showing incorrect minutes

Tags: angular, formatdatetime

I am getting timeIn in GMT+0 from the server and converting it to the clients time using

```
new Date(response[x].timeIn)
```

which gives me the correct time which for e.g is **Thu Dec 10, 2020, 19:15:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)**

but I just want to retrieve the time from it (07:15 PM) for which I used

```
formatDate(new Date(response[x].timeIn), "hh:MM a", 'en-US')
```

but it returns **07:12 PM**.

for every timeIn whether it's 10:00, 14:45, or something else, for the minute part it returns xx:12 in minutes.

Can anyone let me know if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: what does your function `formatDate` look like?

Comment: It's a predefined function in CoomonModule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you are setting the date format incorrectly in `formatDate`.

You are using `MM` which is month, instead of `mm`, which is minutes. That's why you always get 12, because your date is always December.

Try the following code:

```
formatDate(new Date(response[x].timeIn), "hh:mm a", 'en-US')
```

Comment: What a noob mistake. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: no problem. Please accept my answer if it solves your problem.